# Multiple users accessing a micro using a web browser

Tags: security, web, embedded

All,

I am working on a microcontroller (a PIC32MZ to be specific) which can be remotely accessed over the web. The microcontroller offers a working TCP/IP stack implementation, and I can successfully use a browser to communicate with the microcontroller.

If multiple users are accessing the micro, are there established guidelines on how to securely differentiate between the multiple users?

I would like not to re-invent the wheel ... I looked a little into Basic Access control -- but that is a big no-no ...

I also have a login page working, so I can ask for a userName and a password, but do I have to locally create and maintain data structures to manage the various users?

Given the ubiquitous nature of the problem, I would think (hope) that there are established guidelines on how to differentiate amongst, and manage, multiple users in an embedded environment.

I appreciate your help and assistance.

Sincerely,
Vincenzo

**---- EDIT ----**

P.S. -- If I really had to code everything on my own, this is the flowchart I came up with (feedback is again appreciated)

```
browser requests web page and sends a (possibly uninitialized) sessionID

server extracts IP/sessionID

if IP is blacklisted 
{
   deny web page and (re)start timer
}
else                                        // possible legit request
{
    if IP/sessionID is valid                // existing user !
    {
        process request
    }
    else                                    // new user?
    {
        if activeConnections < max AND globalNumberOfFailures < max     // if we have connections available and we are not under attack
        {
            request credentials

            if credentials are valid            // legit user
            {
                create new unique sessionID

                update IP/sessionID table

                process request (and return sessionID)

                activeConnections++
            }
            else                                // distracted user ?
            {
                deny request

                globalNumberOfFailures++ (start timer)  // system wide attack ?

                if first fail for that IP
                {
                    add IP to list of suspicious IPs
                }
                IP_failCounter++

                if IP_failCounter > max
                {
                    blacklist IP, start timer
                }
            }
        }
        else

            deny request
    }
}
```

Comment: If [this applies](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00833c.pdf), then just google for cgi session code.

Comment: In case you never re-set `globalNumberOfFailures` (you don't seem to do it), you might make an easy victim for a DoS attack. So this is probably counter-productive

Comment: Please don't *ever* consider attaching your Pic32MZ to the internet. Tthis sounds alarmingly like you will end up with your device being in the news for not properly securing internet access and so contributing to the demonisation of IoT as the security back passage into a world of internet oblivion. Just because you can serve web pages from a PIC that doesn't mean it is a proper secure web server.

Comment: @Barny -- And the solution is?

Comment: @Barny -- I was trying to edit my previous comment, but I timed-out ...  See below ...  ==> And the solution to securing internet access is ...? As I said in my initial post: "Given the ubiquitous nature of the problem, I would think (hope) that there are established guidelines on how to differentiate amongst, and manage, multiple users in an embedded environment."  On a side note, I am probably posting this same question on the Microchip forum -- and see what comes out of it ...Thank you for your post  ...   :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Person A is visiting site for the first time and he see login form.
   He fill it up and send to your server using http POST method.
2. Your server get the POST method, check if the credentials are valid
   and if everything is ok your server create hash from the string of user login concatenated with current date and time. Hash, login, date&time of auth, are added to some kind of table on your server(it may be even text file). This little precious hash is sent back to your user via 'Set-Cookie' http header.
3. Everytime your server get any http request, your server checks if there is also cookie given with the hash. Server compares cookie with entry in table, check if the time hasn't expired and the server keep in mind this request is made by VIP who logged in.

Implement the above and you are good to go. Look how fun it looks like. Don't pair how you call it 'sessionID' with user ip. It's good to track it somehow but don't deny user who passed valid sessionid from different ip. People with mobile devices tends to often change their ip's.

I think there is no easier way.
It could be fun exercise.